# Error to read matrix when add a function initialize matrix

Tags: c, linked-list

My function transfer matrix from multidimensional arrays to linked list, but when I add a new function to create matrix and show error instead of the first lines

the main function

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse *m, int t[N][M], size_t Nligne, size_t Ncol) {
    //m = creeMat(Nligne, Ncol);
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nligne;
    m->liste = malloc(Nligne * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Nligne; i++) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
        liste_ligne dernier = m->liste[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element *e = creeEle(j, t[i][j]);
                if (dernier != NULL) {
                    dernier->suiv = e;
                    dernier = dernier->suiv;
                } else {
                    dernier = e; 
                    m->liste[i] = dernier;
                }
}}}}
```

new function:

```
matrice_creuse* creeMat(size_t Nligne, size_t Ncol) {
    matrice_creuse *m = malloc(sizeof(matrice_creuse));
    if (m == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return NULL;
    }
    m->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    m->Nlignes = Nligne;
    m->liste = malloc(Nligne * sizeof(liste_ligne));
    if (m->liste == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Nligne ; ++i) {
        m->liste[i] = NULL;
    }
    return m;
}
```

But when add new function into `construcMat`, the function `contrucMat` don't return new matrix which has valuers from matrix t[N][M], `contrucMat` return a parameter matrix `m` Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function contrucMat don't return new matrix which has valuers from matrix t[N][M], contrucMat return a parameter matrix m Null

if you mean after

```
matrice_creuse *m = NULL;
...
construcMat(m, ..);
```

*m* is still NULL this is normal, when you set *m* in *construcMat* you set a local variable, so there is no impact on the caller in the code above

One solution is to not give *m* in parameter of *construcMat* because this is useless but to return it :

```
matrice_creuse *m = construcMat(..);
```

with

```
matrice_creuse * construcMat(int t[N][M], size_t Nligne, size_t Ncol) {
    matrice_creuse * m = creeMat(Nligne, Ncol);
    ...
    return m;
}
```

Else change the profile to use an *in-out* variable :

```
void construcMat(matrice_creuse ** m, int t[N][M], size_t Nligne, size_t Ncol) {
    *m = creeMat(Nligne, Ncol);
    (*m)->Ncolonnes = Ncol;
    (*m)->Nlignes = Nligne;
    (*m)->liste = malloc(Nligne * sizeof(liste_ligne));

    liste_ligne * lignes = (*m)->liste;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Nligne; i++) {
        lignes[i] = NULL;
        liste_ligne * dernier = lignes[i];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ncol; j++) {
            if (t[i][j] != 0) { 
                element *e = creeEle(j, t[i][j]);
                if (dernier != NULL) {
                    dernier->suiv = e;
                    dernier = dernier->suiv;
                } else {
                    dernier = e; 
                    lignes[i] = dernier;
                }
}}}}
```

and the call is changed to be :

```
matrice_creuse *m = NULL;
...
construcMat(&m, ..);
```

---

Warning you missed a "*" in the line `liste_ligne dernier = m->liste[i];`, I corrected in the code above

Comment: how to other solution? follow my teacher, the function construcMat must be type void

Comment: @TranQuocGiaCat is it ok ? you understand ?

Comment: in function `main` I  initialize parameter `matrice_creuse m`, how to pass double point from function `construcMat`

Comment: @TranQuocGiaCat as I did in my answer, with `&m` rather than just`m`. Warning I see an error in your code and edited my answer